# Why do I get the "Maximum update depth exceeded" error?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

After I added a check for an authorized user in routes, I started getting an infinite re-render error.

App.js:

```
function App(props) {

    useEffect(() => props.checkUserToken() , []); // action проверяющий, есть ли JWT в localStorage, если да, то меняет props.isLogin на true
  
    return (
        <div className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/authorization'
                       render={props => !props.isLogin ? <Login {...props} /> : <Redirect to='/main' />}
                />

                <Route path='/main'
                       render={props => props.isLogin ? <MainPage {...props} /> : <Redirect to='/authorization' />}
                />
                <Route
                    render={props => <Redirect to={props.isLogin ? '/main' : '/authorization'} />}
                />
            </Switch>
            {
                props.loading && <Loading />
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here's what the redux-logger outputs:

[Here's what the redux-logger outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Bm4Y.png)

First, action "CHECK_TOKEN" is called (don't pay attention to persist), which is listened to by the Saga and, depending on the result of the check, it calls action "TOKEN_EXIST", which changes isLogin to true in theory, then the App should re-render, again "go" to the authorization route and redirect to main, but an error POPs up.

At first I thought it was about checking the token, so I commented on the hook, re-logged in, but everything was repeated, authorization was successful, data was received, isLogin became true, but again this error came out.

Debugger and console.log do not work if you put them in MainPage, in action and sagas, I am also sure, because they all worked perfectly (and still work), until I changed the routes (made a check)

- as I wrote above, this error only POPs up when isLogin changes to true and a redirect should occur.

Full error code:

[Full error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ThU3Q.png)

So what is the problem and how do I fix this error? Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Probably `/authorization` redirects to `/main` and `/main` redirects to `/authorization`

Comment: @MihályiZoltán, hello, you are right, when i changed  route `/main` render for `to={MainPage}` error disappeared. But why does the redirect to `/authorization` work, if props.isLogin = true

Answer (score 0):

Found it! As always the mistake is in the small things)

```
<Route path= '/authorization'
render={props => !props.isLogin ? <MainPage {...props} /> : <Redirect to='/main' />}
/>
```

In a similar entry, a props.isLogin of the LE (Lexical Environment) function in the render, and there it is equal to undefined, so the false condition is constantly triggered, and there is an infinite redirect from /main to the /authorization.
The solution is to change the name of the props parameter to any other name)

Example:

```
<Route path='/authorization'
render={lalala => !props.isLogin ? <MainPage {...lalala} /> : <Redirect to='/authorization' />}
/>
```